# Grabbing users with no orders with mysql & php, simplifying this

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Currently, this is my php script:

```
            $users = DB::select('id', 'email', 'firstname', 'lastname')->from('users')->execute()->as_array();

            $orders = array();
            foreach($users as $user)
            {
                $anyOrder = DB::select('id')->from('orders')
                ->where('orders.date_created', 'BETWEEN', array($from, $to))
                ->and_where('orders.user_id', '=', $user['id'])
                ->and_where_open()
                ->and_where('orders.status', '=', 'new')->or_where('orders.status', '=', 'delivered')
                ->and_where_close()
                ->execute()->count();

                if($anyOrder == 0)
                {
                    $orders[] = array('firstname' => $user['firstname'], 'lastname' => $user['lastname'], 'email' => $user['email']);
                }
            }
```

(DB::select() is a query, im using kohana query builder).

This works fine, until now when I have over thousands users.

How can this be simplified and quicker?

What the script does is saving all who does not have an order between $from and $to into the $orders array.

Answer (score 1):

Use a SQL join-query and select for no order results.  Along the lines of

```
SELECT id, email, firstname, lastname
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON users.id = orders.user_id
    AND orders.date_created BETWEEN $start AND $end
    AND orders.status = 'new' OR orders.status = 'delivered'
WHERE orders.id IS NULL
```

Using a join is much better, as you will get everything you need in one query, instead of one per user.
Thanks to the person who edited the query :)

Comment: if i use a join: 
SELECT id,email,firstname,lastname FROM users 
INNER JOIN orders ON (orders.user_id = users.id)
WHERE (...)

Then i will get all the users that has orders. I wish to grab the users that: 1. does not have any rows in orders 2. have rows in orders but they are not status "delivered" or "new"

Comment: INNER JOIN requires a user to have an order. left join says return all users even if they don't have an order. [Consider](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Not sure if I understand: Then select all users and subtract the users found here.

Comment: `SELECT id, email, firstname, lastname
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON users.id = orders.user_id
    AND orders.date_created BETWEEN $start AND $end
WHERE (orders.id IS NULL OR orders.status not in ('new','delivered'))`

Comment: @xQbert Just tried that query too, and i get timeout 500 error, like i did with the script.

Comment: how did you use it? With this solution, you should only do ONE query.

Answer (score 0):

/*Get all users without any orders*/

```
SELECT id, email, firstname, lastname 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN orders 
  ON users.id = orders.user_id 
  AND orders.date_created BETWEEN $start AND $end 
WHERE orders.id IS NULL
UNION
```

/*Union in all users */

```
(SELECT id, email, firstname, lastname 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN orders 
  ON users.id = orders.user_id 
  AND orders.date_created BETWEEN $start AND $end
```

/* except those with 'new' & 'delivered' status

/*note: if user bob has 2 orders and one is in status of 'backorder' and one is in 'new'
then bob will show up... is this what you want? */

```
MINUS
SELECT id, email, firstname, lastname 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN orders 
  ON users.id = orders.user_id 
  AND orders.date_created BETWEEN $start AND $end
WHERE Orders.status in ('new','delivered'))
```